# Is this sentence Participial Construction?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, participle-clauses

> When it comes to social policy, President Trump embraces conservative politics as usual, continuing a nearly four-decades-long effort to make these policies more restrictive. (excerpt from NYT *[The Welfare Boogeyman](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/07/23/opinion/trump-social-policies-welfare.html)* (July 23, 2018) by Suzanne Mettler)

I definitely understand the main clause and know what the "continuing ---" sentence means, but I'm confusing whether it is a so-called participial construction. If so, does that mean that "President Trump" has continued a long-standing effort to make social policies restrictive? Or is there other grammatical/semantic subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a participial construction: **continuing** is the present participle of *to continue*, and the "continuing a nearly..." phrase describes something about the main clause ("President Trump embraces conservative politics as usual").

You could think of it this way:

> President Trump embraces conservative politics as usual.
>   This action (President Trump's embracing of conservative politics as usual) continues a nearly four-decades-long effort to make these policies more restrictive.